# Android Volley JsonArrayRequest

Tags: php, android, android-volley

The PHP that gives me a list of records through a SQL returns me the following:

```
$result = $con->query($query);
for ($set = array (); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = json_encode($row));
print_r($set);

RESULTADO
Array
(
[0] => {"id":"8783","nombre":"pepe","username":"demo"}
[1] => {"id":"8784","nombre":"garcia","username":"demo"}
)
```

Now as a process that from Android with Volley, I have the following but obviously not working:

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_2,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        String nombre = jsonObject.getString("name");
                                        Log.e("nombre", nombre);
                                        mEntries.add(jsonObject.toString());

                                    }
                                    catch(JSONException e) {
                                        mEntries.add("Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                    }
```

ERROR:

> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Array of
>   Type  java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

I modify the volley by leaving only the following within the try and it throws the same error

```
try {
   Integer cantidad = jsonArray.length();
   Log.e("cantidad: ", cantidad.toString());
}
```

I try with this and continue the same error

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
   for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
      try {
        Log.i("SUCCESS", response.toString());
      }
.....
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

change your php file

```
$result = $con->query($query);
json_encode(["result" => $result]);
```

and in `onResponse`  add:

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    JsonArray myData = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);
```

Comment: Lo pruebo con Postman y me arroja esto

{"result":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}}

Comment: Con este código

$result = $con->query($query2);

echo json_encode(["result" => $result]);

Comment: in english please